# Linphone iOS SDK integration returns unknown assembly

Tags: xamarin.ios, dllimport, linphone, linphone-sdk

I have implemented Linphone Xamarin Documentation [doc](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Xamarin/#Information)
I imported the frameworks inside the iOS project and added them in Native Reference. the problem is the library does not have any file extension unlike any objective c framework which has `.a` file extension. It does have headers.

The android part of the SDK has `.so` file extension for the specific framework.

```
[DllImport(LinphoneWrapper.LIB_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr linphone_factory_get();
```

returns `System.DllNotFoundException`

`linphone.framework/linphone assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)`

I added the LinphoneWrappper in a  c# project and referenced it on my iOS project.

Any inputs about this will help. :)